# Does "lifetime of up quark" have a physical meaning?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, elementary-particles

I saw [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/477395/60646) question about the lifetime of an up quark.

As far as I know, free quarks are [never observed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement) in experiments. Then what is the significance of a statement like "the lifetime of an up quark is X units"?

I am looking for a physical explanation without involving much mathematics. I am not very familiar with the mathematical formulation of QCD, but I know about Feynman diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "lifetime of an up quark" is utterly ***meaningless*** (at least here, but I'd be hard pressed to find legitimate contexts for it...).

The lifetime discussed is that of a neutral pion, decaying by the F diagram (sorry)  [image]

In words, the pion "resolves" to virtual states of its valence quarks, *u* or *d*, which then couple to two real photons, to which the pion thus decays with a given width (/lifetime) thus computed.

The lifetime discussion never applied to the quarks, but only to the *size* of the amplitude represented by this diagram/process. This size eventually determines the probability of decay per unit of time, related to the lifetime.

Comment: The bottom arrow in the triangle should point towards the left (as it is an anti up or anti down quark).

Comment: Yes, that’s the best I could find to borrow…